# Issue when restoring Content Databases

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, content-database, restore

I am trying to restore a production database in my UAT environment for testing purposes but something wrong is happening.

I am able to restore the database via SQL MS, without any errors. Then the database attachment occurs without any errors too and the Content Database shows on my Central Admin normally. But when I try to access the respective collection I get the following error:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 Date: Fri, 03 Mar 2017
>   17:38:38 GMT Connection: close

This doesn't happen to all content dbs I try to restore, but to most of them. Any clue of what I am doing wrong?

A few things I already tried:

- Restarting IIS
- Validated that the DB schema is correct
- There is no error log in the event viewer

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this kind of situation all of times. Two things fix my issues most of time.

1. Detach the DB (which is having issue) from the central admin. Now mount it using the powershell. After this test the site collections.
2. Run the refresh Sites in configuration using the following commands.

   $db = Get-SPDatabase | where {$_.Name -eq "DatabaseName"}
   $db.RefreshSitesInConfigurationDatabase()

Now test the site collections.

Another thing, try to create new site collections in the problematic content database.